# menu_navigation_links() generate a error

Tags: 7, routes

I'm try listing a menu navigation links with menu_navigation_links() function, but is generate a follow error:

> Notice: Undefined index: localized_options in menu_navigation_links() (line 1860 of /home3/xptoboxc/public_html/drupal/includes/menu.inc).

**My code:**

```
$html .='<ul id="navigation" class="arrow-list">';
foreach (menu_navigation_links('navigation') as $menu => $link) {
    if(!empty($link['title']))
        $html .= '<li><a href="' . url($link['href']) . '" title="' . $link['title'] . '">' . $link['title'] . '</a></li>';
}
$html .= '</ul>';
```

Answer (score 2):

Are you using the navigation menu as the secondary menu for the site?

The cause could be a bug in drupal core. See http://drupal.org/node/1018614

There is a patch in #83, which I think is for drupal 8 but the fix should be the same for drupal 7.

Comment: seems patch at #83 is a D7 patch: see: https://drupal.org/comment/8346823#comment-8346823

Answer (score 0):

try this code:

```
$html .='<ul id="navigation" class="arrow-list">';
foreach (menu_navigation_links('navigation') as $menu => $link) {
    if(!empty($link['title']))
        $linkt = t($link['title']);
        $html .= '<li><a href="' . url($link['href']) . '" title="' . $link['title'] . '">' . $linkt . '</a></li>';
}
$html .= '</ul>';
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. but the line that generates the error is: ``foreach (menu_navigation_links('navigation') as $menu => $link) {``

Comment: which drupal version u using?

Comment: my version is 7.19